# Code contracts on auto-implemented properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties, code-contracts, automatic-properties

Is there any way to put contracts on automatically implemented properties in .NET?
(And how if the answer is 'Yes')?

(I assume using .NET code contracts from DevLabs)

Comment: Have you tried using class invarients for this purpose? I suspect that would work, unless the invarients are not checked when returning from an auto-prop setter. (I am not yet running a version of VS with code contracts, so I can't test this myself. I don't know if I will ever get a version with the static checker. :-( )

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the invariants will be checked in the Release version of the project, because for this configuration I've turned on the option "Only public surface contracts", which I suspect to deal only with Contract.Requires in public methods. I'd be happy if I'm wrong.

Comment: But I'm afraid I'm right: "...You can add invariant methods to enforce data integrity (Section 2.3) ... These checks
are enforced in your testing builds with runtime checking enabled, but disappear from your shipping code."

Comment: I believe that Invariants on auto-implemented properties actually add the Requires and Ensures. Need to double-check this though...

Comment: I've made a custom check with checking option "ReleaseRequires" - which is surely to be used in the Release configuration - and the invariant wasn't checked at all, including the requirements related to the auto-property. No matter if the flag "public surface contracts only" was checked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Porges.

My mistake was that I actually used `ReleaseRequires` option, which, indeed, deals only with **generic** version of the method,  `Requires<T>`.

Invariant which is put on an auto-implemented property is **really turned into a** `Requires` precondition, but it's not generic - that's why it didn't work using this option.

What to do:

- VARIANT 1. Consider using code snippets and lovely `Requires<T>` instead of auto-implemented properties - that enables us to use exceptions of desired type.
- VARIANT 2. **Change the option** `ReleaseRequires` to `Preconditions` in the Code Contracts' options and feel free to write invariants on auto-properties - the rewriter tool will automatically change them into the `Requires`. However, they will be non-generic - that means, in case of contract broken, a `ContractException` will be thrown and there is no way to change this behaviour.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 16):

Yes, this is possible - all that is needed is to add your contract condition to the `[ContractInvariantMethod]` method in your class, which then adds the equivalent `Requires` precondition to the automatic `set`ter, and a post condition `Ensures` is added to the `get`. From section 2.3.1 of the [Reference](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf)

> As the example illustrates, invariants on auto-properties turn into:
>
> 1. A precondition for the setter
> 2. A postcondition for the getter
> 3. An invariant for the underlying backing field

And by example:

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set ;}

[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant ()
{
  Contract.Invariant ( this.MyProperty >= 0 );
}
```

"Is equivalent to the following code:"

```
private int backingFieldForMyProperty;
public int MyProperty 
{
  get 
  {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
    return this.backingFieldForMyProperty;
  }

  private set 
  {
    Contract.Requires(value >= 0);
    this.backingFieldForMyProperty = value;
  }
}

[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant () 
{
  Contract.Invariant ( this.backingFieldForMyProperty >= 0 );
...
```

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking not, but you could easily write a snippet that would do this. If you go this route, [here is a free snippet editor](http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/) that will make the task very easy.